# mongodb aggregate, sort based on lookup result

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have the following data architecture ( I am reporting only few fields)

Collection order

```
| id    | service | customer |
|-------|---------|----------|
| O001  | SRV001  | CST001   |
| O002  | SRV001  | CST001   |
| O003  | SRV001  | CST002   |
| O004  | SRV002  | CST003   |
| O005  | SRV002  | CST002   |
| O006  | SRV003  | CST004   |
```

Collection customer

```
| id     | name    | city     |
|--------|---------|----------|
| CST001 | Paul    | New York |
| CST002 | Anna    | London   |
| CST003 | John    | Milan    |
| CST004 | Julia   | Paris    |
```

Suppose I want to sort my order for customer's name

The idea was to use a aggregate with a $lookup to join customer to order and sort the result

```
db.order.aggregate([
   { $lookup: { 'foreignField': 'id', 
                'as': '__customer', 
                'from': 'customer', 
                'localField':'customer'} },
   { $unwind: '$__customer'},
   { $sort:   { '__customer.name': 1 } }
])
```

This works fine if you have limited data. If you have a large amount of data it does not work because the sort is executed on a $lookup result so mongodb does not have a index to use even if the field "name" in the customer collection has a index.

I think there is no way to achieve this.

Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes) says:

> The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index when they occur at the **beginning** of the pipeline.

and more:

> Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, indexes can cover an aggregation pipeline. In MongoDB 2.6 and 3.0, indexes could not cover an aggregation pipeline since even when the pipeline uses an index, aggregation still requires access to the actual documents.

According to this, MongoDB (3.2 and higher) aggregation use indexes.

There are some tricks for your pipeline however. For example, you may aggregate `customer` table, not `order`. Sort it and then do `lookup` for `orders`.

Or you can `group` by `customer` and then do `lookup`. I don't think it will work faster (actually I think it will be slower) but you can try and think it out.

And don't forget use `matches` and `limits` - they speed up aggregation. Even in big pipeline you often can `match` closer to beginning, sometimes you need to think well though.

Comment: Aggregate customer table is not an option because the relation is not 1 to 1

Comment: I need a generic solution some filters (implemented with matches) could be present but the worst case is when it is not present.

Comment: @lorenzo you don't need 1 to 1 relation. `lookup` for a field `id` with `unwind` do gives you 1 to 1 relation, but when you then `sort` by `customer.name` you get `many orders to 1 customer` relation and that's the same thing that will do sorting `customers` and `lookup` for `orders` (without `unwind` for `orders`). You'll get a list with customers (with lists of orders within). And here you have common situation - if you need only first 20 orders then you can limit(20) your customers, then `unwind` orders, sort by customer (because unwind can sort by itself) and limit(20) again.

Comment: @Lorenzo just to ensure we talk of the same thing, that is my suggested pipeline:
```db.customer.aggregate([
    {$sort: {'name': 1}},
    {$lookup: {
        'localField':'_id',
        'from': 'order', 
        'foreignField': 'customer', 
        'as': 'orders',
    }},
    {$match: {orders: {$gt: []}}},
    {$limit: 20},
    {$unwind: '$orders'},
    {$limit: 20},
])
```

Comment: Thanks I will have a look next week. I am not at home this week